# unable to use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE with bulk collect into

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bulkinsert

This is the first time I am trying to write a PL/SQL.

I have a table `T_TRANSACTION` with multiple columns. I want my PL/SQL to initially extract the distinct values of certain column called `mandant` and save it to a cursor. then I want to write a for loop in which for each `mandant` from the cursor my main query does some stuff.

The main query is a basic select which apparently does not work in PL/SQL and that is why I used select into and since it returns more than 1 row I saw I have to use BULK collect into.  I have a ready pl/sql now which technically works but I can not output the results (can not correctly use the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`) and therefore I do not know if this is correct.  here is the PL/SQL:

```
declare 
    cursor c1 is
        SELECT distinct mandant  from T_TRANSACTION;
        type mytab is table of VARCHAR2(20);
        colname mytab := mytab();
        colval mytab := mytab();
        colcount mytab := mytab();

BEGIN

     for i in c1
     loop
                select 'PARTNER_ID' as column_name, to_char(col), cnt bulk collect into colname, colval, colcount
                from (select PARTNER_ID as col, count(*) as cnt
                            from T_TRANSACTION
                            where SML like '181031%A' and mandant = i.mandant
                            group by PARTNER_ID 
                            order by count(*)desc) 
                 where rownum <=3
                 connect by level <=3;

    end loop;

    -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (colname || colval || colcount);
end;
```

and this is my table `T_TRANSACTION`:

```
   CREATE TABLE T_TRANSACTION 
   (    MANDANT CHAR(5 CHAR), 
    SML VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    RUN CHAR(1 CHAR), 
    SL_PARTNER_RISK VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    GESCHAEFT_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    PARTNER_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    TRANS_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE);
```

in the query below I am getting the top 3 values of column `PARTNER_ID` for each `mandant` from the cursor.

My second question actually would how could I do this for all columns of the table without repeating the query. Later I want to use this for many different tables and therefore I want to extract the column of for each table for example from all_tab_columns and then run the query I posted for all columns of every table. But I do not know how to do so in PL/SQL.  I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Cursors don't "save" anything. A cursor provides a way to iterate through the result set of a SELECT statement, but it is not not a data storage method.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking but you say DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line is not working.... DBMS_OUTPUT takes a parameter of varchar2, in your example code you are trying to pass it variables of type mytab (table of varchar2's).  To use DBMS_OUTPUT to output the values from these you would need to iterate through them outputting each value.

Answer (score 1):

After data is fetched, you have to use another loop (from the *first* to the *last* element) (lines 10 - 12 in my example) and then display those values.

Have a look at this example, based on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    t_deptno sys.odcinumberlist;
  3    t_dname  sys.odcivarchar2list;
  4    cursor cur_r is select deptno, dname from dept;
  5  begin
  6    open cur_r;
  7    fetch cur_r bulk collect into t_deptno, t_dname;
  8    close cur_r;
  9
 10    for i in t_deptno.first .. t_deptno.last loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line(t_deptno(i) ||' '|| t_dname(i));
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
10 ACCOUNTING
20 RESEARCH
30 SALES
40 OPERATIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: well. thank you but it would be very helpfull if you could comment on my example. I shee in your example you are bulking the cursor into your declared tables.. this is not really what I want to do. could you please comment on my example?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, this is exactly what you are doing - the difference is in a type of the *target* - you declared your own type, I used built-in ones. As of using ALL_TAB_COLUMNS: you'll have to use dynamic SQL for that, I'd say.

Comment: to me it is like I am not writing the cursor into my declared tables, but I use the values from my cursor in my main select query and write these selects into declared tables! whereas you directly write the cursor table into declared tables. am I wrong? :)